# VBA Macro No Longer Working with IE Protected Mode

Tags: excel, vba

So I've used this code for years to copy data from Excel into text box fields of a website using internet explorer. Recently I upgraded to Windows 10 and it's no longer working.

However it will work when I turn off Protected Mode in the security settings of Internet explorer. The problem is I have to leave this mode on for security concerns.

Does anyone know if it's possible to turn Protected Mode off and then back on using VBA code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just add current domain to whitelist ?

Comment: Unfortunately adding a trusted site is greyed out by our IT department :(

Comment: Can IT add it for you?

Comment: Hopefully! I'm waiting on a response now about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable "Websites with less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone" ins browser's settings, or add website to "Trusted sites". Also you can try to create an instance of Internet Explorer running at a medium integrity level: `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium`

If that doesn't work, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642519/getting-or-setting-internet-explorer-options-with-vba) might help you.

Comment: Still no luck with changing the settings. I'll take a look at the registry solution someone came up with in that link.